# In a custom module how do I get all the nodes of a certain type?

Tags: nodes, database

Do I just do a direct `db_query()` on node/node_revision, or is there a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `db_query()` to get the node IDs for all the nodes of a content type, and then [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/6) to load the single nodes one by one.

```
$query = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = '%s'", $type);

while ($result = db_fetch_object($query)) {
  $node = node_load($result->nid);
  // Use $node or store it in an array;
}
```

As the query is fetching a single field, `db_fetch_object()` could probably be replaced with [db_result()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_result/6); I have never checked if it works for all the database engines, and I didn't find a Drupal core module that uses `db_result()` in a loop (e.g., `while ($nid = db_result($query))`).

The reason you should use `node_load()` is that:

- It allows the module that define the content type for the loaded node, and third-party modules to add extra fields in the node object. This is because the function uses the following code:

  ```
  // Call the node specific callback (if any) and piggy-back the
  // results to the node or overwrite some values.
  if ($extra = node_invoke($node, 'load')) {
    foreach ($extra as $key => $value) {
      $node->$key = $value;
    }
  }

  if ($extra = node_invoke_nodeapi($node, 'load')) {
    foreach ($extra as $key => $value) {
      $node->$key = $value;
    }
  }
  ```
- It loads the correct node revision, when revisions are enabled for the content type.
- It caches the result; if two calls to the functions are requiring the same node, the function simply return the previous result. This happens if the call to the function doesn't require a specific revision of the module, and if the last parameter passed to the function (`$reset`) is not equal to `TRUE`.

If you are interested to get only the node ID, then the call to `db_query()` is sufficient.

In Drupal 7, there is a class that allows to load multiple entities (Drupal 7 nodes are entities) that match some criteria in once: [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7).

Answer (score 3):

You do a query with `db_query()`

```
db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = 'type';");
```