# How to get a field's value for all nodes in a content type?

Tags: 7, entities

I would like to get values of a field from all nodes of a content type. How can I do this? EntityFieldQuery seems to return only node ids, so will I need db_query? Sg similar to this [In a custom module how do I get all the nodes of a certain type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8956/in-a-custom-module-how-do-i-get-all-the-nodes-of-a-certain-type)

I guess I just need to lookup the table name of the field...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, you can probably simply query the field data table, with a condition on the entity type and bundle.

In any case, something like:

```
$field_name = 'FIELD_NAME';
$result = db_select("field_data_{$field_name}", 'f')
  ->fields('f', array('entity_id', "{$field_name}_value"))
  ->condition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->condition('bundle', 'article')
  ->condition('deleted', 0)
  ->range(0,10)
  ->execute();

foreach ($result as $row) {
  // drupal_set_message($row->field_name_value); // example
  drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($row,1).'</pre>');
}
```

As an aside you might want to join on the node table to only select published content, but that's the gist of it.